# Is there an algorithm on python for analyzing swarming behavior or a modeling algorithm to predict swarming behavior?

Tags: algorithms

Is there an algorithm on python to analyze swarming behavior or model swarming behavior for predictions?

Comment: As it stands, this question is far too broad for this format.